# Why does the following result in segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
const int* additional(int* s, int* f){
    const int* ts = reinterpret_cast<const int*>(*s + *f);
    return ts;
}
int main() {
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    const int* oc = additional(&a, &b);
    std::cout << *oc;
    return 0;
}
```

> I've tried using static, although it produces the same error

Comment: `*s + *f` is an int, not a pointer. `s` and `f` are non-existent once the function returns either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your code.
`*s + *f` is an int, not a pointer (you add the dereferenced values).
you are doing a `reinterpret cast` which isn't needed at all. Just pass the int's directly without pointers and you are good to go.

```
const int additional(int s, int f){
    return s + f;
}
int main() {
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    const int oc = additional(a, b);
    std::cout << oc;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You reinterpret the number 30 as a pointer to const int and attempt to read through the reinterpreted pointer. The operating system noticed that the process was attempting to access an address wasn't mapped for the process and sent the segfault signal to terminate the process in order to protect the badly behaving process from itself.

Reinterpret casting is unsafe. Don't use it unless you know what you're doing. And when you know what you're doing, you'll know that it's quite rare to need to use it.

> I was aiming to shorten the `int t = *f + *s`;

That is already extremely short. The function that you defined is much longer and so is even a call to the function. Note that the initialiser expression that you quote has type `int` while your function returns `const int*`. That, along with the broken reinterpret cast are the problem.

If you wanted to make the indirection shorter, then how about using references instead of pointers:

```
const int& f = a;
const int& s = b;
int t = a + b; // shorter
```

Comment: I was completely aware and deliberately dereferenced the parameters in an attempt to make the locally created pointer point to the multiplication of the dereferenced values thereby, hence making it accessible to main. As pretentious as It might be, I was aiming to shorten the  `int t = *f + *s;` . So now the question is, is it possible to actually implement this "shortening", so to speak? Yes, I'm new.